# Python Pandas Apply, Pass Dictionary as Argument

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pass a dictionary as an additional argument to a function. The function is to be applied over each row of a data frame. So I use 'apply'. Below I have a small example of my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def fun(df_row, dict1):
 return df_row['A']*2*max(dict1['x'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,2),columns=list('AB'))
dict_test = {'x': [1,2,3,4], 'y': [5,6,7,8]}
df['D'] = df.apply(fun, args = (dict_test), axis = 1)
```

I get the following error message:
    ('fun() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)', u'occurred at index 0')
I use **dict1 to indicate key-value pairs in the function 'fun'

Curiously enough if I pass two arguements, things work fine

```
def fun(df_row, dict1, dict2):
 return df_row['A']*2*max(dict1['x'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,2),columns=list('AB'))
dict_test = {'x': [1,2,3,4], 'y': [5,6,7,8]}
df['D'] = df.apply(fun, axis = 1,  args = (dict_test, dict_test))
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `**`.  The dictionary will be passed in as a normal argument, not as keyword arguments.

Comment: If I remove ** I get the error ('fun() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)', u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: If you define `fun()` to take `*args` and print `args`, it should give you an idea of what data is being passed to it.  You definitely need to add another parameter to your function, but that should tell you what it is.

Comment: It seems to be passing only the keys of the dictionary and not the key-value pairs. This is one row :  `(A   -0.207240
B    1.193103
Name: 0, dtype: float64, 'y', 'x')
`

Comment: Hi. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve: if `dict_test` items are passed as keyword arguments, you'll end up with `dict1['x'] ` that is *a list of 4 ints* that you'll try to multiply with `df["A"] * 2`... That just won't work. I get this is a toy example but if you could clarify that point that would make the question easier to answer.

Comment: @ldirer, thanks, edited the function

Comment: Damn typos ;)... You're using `df` in your `fun` where you probably meant `df_row`.

Comment: @ldirer Damn typos :D edited again

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing a tuple, `(dict_test)` is not a tuple, it's just the same as `dict_test`. You want a tuple with `dict_test` as the only element, that is `(dict_test,)`.

```
df['D'] = df.apply(fun, args=(dict_test,), axis=1)
```

Comment: What is the comma for in `args=(dict_test,)`?

Comment: @conchoecia It is for [creating a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple).

Answer (score 1):

From `pd.DataFrame.apply` doc:

> ```
> Parameters
> ----------
> ...
> args : tuple
>     Positional arguments to pass to function in addition to the
>     array/series
> Additional keyword arguments will be passed as keywords to the function
> ```

That last line means that if you want to unpack `dict_test` to pass arguments *as keywords* to `fun`, you can do:

```
df['D'] = df.apply(fun, axis=1, **dict_test)
```

Previously you were using:

```
df['D'] = df.apply(fun, args = (dict_test), axis = 1)
```

That means `apply` will try to call `fun` this way:

```
fun(df_row, dict_test)
```

But this is **not** how you defined `fun` (you'll get the difference once you know a bit more about positional and keyword arguments).

Comment: Still doesn't work: `("fun() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'", u'occurred at index 0')
`

Comment: That's a bit weird. Are you passing `**dict_test` **after** all the other arguments to apply?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you typed it

Comment: Hmmm. I tested it and it works on my side. With the way you defined fun you should be able to call `fun({"A": 1}, x=[1], y=2)` without an error. Can you check that?

Comment: Yes, I think I was making an error. It works. So in `apply` I can't use `args` to pass dictionaries?

Comment: You newest edit and this remark suggest you should take some time to read about arguments, keyword arguments and dictionary unpacking ;). Basically the way you defined `fun` **dict1 is not expected as a regular argument**. Instead it contains *keyword arguments*. You can definitely pass a dictionary using `args` in apply, but then you need your function to be expecting a dictionary. You can do that with: `def fun(df_row, dict1):..`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am a little confused about keyword arguments and passing dictionaries as arguments. I will read up on that